# On to Jquery Ajax call , getting the whole HTM content as response

Tags: jquery

This is my Server side coding on to the JSP

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<%

int number = 10;
    out.println("The Returned response as per the hardcoded values is "+number);
%>
</html>
```

As you can see that , i am returrning an number as the response for an AJAX call

And on to the Script.js file , i am handling it in this way :

```
                                 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "calculate.jsp",
       dataType: "html",
        success : function(msg) {
            var pinNumber = msg;
            alert(pinNumber);
        }
    });
```

As a result of this , i am getting the whole HTMl content as response as shown in the figure 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vy431w&s=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, because you also included some HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
```

Remove the HTML tags and it will work. Afaik, the JS works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you do render `<html><head>`. You could remove those or

simple way is:

```
success : function(msg) {
    alert($(msg).text());
}
```

Harder but probably cleaner way is:

```
out.println("<div>The Returned response as per the hardcoded values is "+number+"</div>");

....

success : function(msg) {
    var pinNumber = $("div", $(msg));
    alert(pinNumber.html());
}
```